# Count whitespaces between cursor and preceding non space character

Tags: vimscript

In case I have the following line

```
// Component: <Component name here>                          |
```

where `|` is the cursor marker. How can I count, using vimscript, the total number of white spaces before the cursor until the first non space character (`>` in this case) ?

The aim is to delete all preceding whitespace before cursor, until non first space character (excluding it).

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you explained what you're trying to accomplish in the bigger picture. Give some context. Counting whitespace is hardly something you do for its own sake.

Comment: I updated the question for clearness.

Comment: FWIW, you can use `diw` without calculating anything, here.

Comment: I know it, my purpose was to map `C-Backspace` to delete previous word or white spaces. I solved anyway.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and remove it from your question.

Comment: I've removed the "answer" from you Question. Please post answers down below as Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to the question:

```
inoremap <silent> <expr> <nowait> <C-Del> getline('.')[col('.')-1] == ' ' ? "<C-o>dw" : getline('.')[col('.')-1:] =~ '\w' ? "<C-o>diw" : "<Del>"
inoremap <silent> <expr> <nowait> <C-Backspace> col('.') == 1 ? "<Backspace>" : getline('.')[col('.') - 2] == ' ' ? "<C-o>ge<Right><C-o>dw" : getline('.') == '\s\+' ? "<C-o>g0<C-o>dw" : "<C-o>db"
```

Comment: How does this solves the problem at hand? Can you explain the logic of this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of white spaces character you could do:

```
let l = getline('.')
let n = len(l) - match(l, '\s*$')
```

If you want to count the number of white spaces you could do:

```
let bnr = bufnr('%')
let winid = bufwind(bnr)

let r = line('.')
let l = getline(r)
let c0 = match(l, '\s*$') - 1
let c1 = len(l) + 1
let n0 = screenpos(winid, r, c0)
let n1 = screenpos(winid, r, c1)
let n = n1 - n0
```